# In Rails should objects be limited to those that will have a view and controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I've been struggling with a design problem, and I admit that I am new to both OOP and RoR so I'm sure this is going to be very basic.  I have an application where I am reading from text files in various formats in order to parse information related to hands of poker.  So what I have are three entities:

- A file object.  This stores the name and path of the file and some other attributes, and has functions related to reading from the files.  This is MVC because I can add a file and have it be auto-updated, or I can just parse the info from a file on the fly.
- The poker hand object.  This essentially just stores information about who played the hand of poker and what the actions and results were.
- A parser.  This reads external JSON files with different regex patterns depending on the type of file that is being read.  It also has some basic state machine info in the JSON file so that alot of the logic is removed from the parser.

So my initial feeling about the parser was that it should be its own object.  But then I realized that it didn't have a V or a C and so possibly didn't fit with the Rails way of doing things.  And it also doesn't have any functionality that is needed by any object other than the file object, and so seemed to fit within the file.  But at the same time it's so distinctly different than a file object, that it didn't seem to fit.  I thought of a module, but the point of modules seems to be if multiple objects share the need for some functions, and in this case only the file does.

So should it be its own object, be within the file object, or is there some other alternative I'm not seeing?

Comment: It does not belong to a file object but you can add it as class function in the model for the file object. i.e. if Document is the model of file obect, you can define `self.parse_info(info)` in the Document model, so that you can call it like `Document.parse_info(json_string)`. It will be a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: Sorry, I can understand having the parsing methods be part of the File class, and that they would be separate from a File instance.  But I don't understand where the Document model is coming in.  Are you assuming that File should be a inherited from a Document?  Why would parsing make more sense in relation to a Document than a File, and would it be worth having a Document class just to remove the parsing from the File class?  I appreciate the advise, but am just trying to understand..

Comment: I was assuming that you will have a model named `Document`(or whatever you want) to represent your files with attributes name, path of the file etc. `Document` is just a name I gave to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision about whether something should be an "M" in MVC should be based on whether it has any persistent (database-driven) data.

Models don't need a controller or views, and controllers don't have to map one-to-one with models. However, the common "RESTful API" approach does result in a strong model <=> controller correspondence.

In your case it sounds like it's just a chunk of code which takes input and returns some other already-defined model, so it probably sits best as a module in your `lib/` folder which you can call from some of your other models or controllers

Comment: I had read somewhere that modules were for separating out code that will be used by more than one object when the code doesn't "belong" to any of them.  It seems like if a function is only used by one object that it should be tied to it somehow. Is being used by more than one object not really a requirement for making a module?

Comment: Module is a way of doing multiple inheritance. It's like implementing an interface in other language, but the implementation is already done for you, so you just mix it in.

Comment: re: "The decision about whether something should be an 'M' in MVC should be based on whether it has any persistent (database-driven) data. - just as another view on this: I think it's perfectly acceptable to have non-DB-related classes as a Model. In fact, I came to this question with the desire to answer simply "No!" to it's title, in giant red 200 point font.

Comment: Sammy, but my question about modules comes up again in your comment.  You mention that is meant for multiple inheritance across objects, so does that mean it should only be used in cases where multiple objects need it?  If only one object will call the functions in a module, does it make more sense to incorporate it as a class function?

Comment: @Jeremy: There are many possible uses for modules, *one* of which is multiple inheritance. It's certainly not wrong to use a module if only one class needs access to it.

Answer (score 1):

> But then I realized that it didn't have a V or a C and so possibly didn't fit with the Rails way of doing things.

The fact that it doesn't have a V or C is irrelevant in my opinion.

If you feel like the parser belongs with the File, then stick it there. But if you don't (and to me it doesn't sound like it), it's perfectly OK to stick it in it's own class. There is no need that all Models have associated Controllers and Views, nor that they derive from ActiveRecord::Base or any other ORM, nor have anything to do with the database whatsoever.

Regarding whether it belongs in lib or app/models - I look at it like this:

If it's part of your app, it belongs in app/models. If it's not part of your app, like an external library, don't put it in app/models - put it in the lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your parser should be a utility class, rather than part of the model itself. Think of it this way: the model should comprise all of the *logic* which your application needs to do its job. The parser's job is to get external data into a format which that logic can work on; it's not part of the logic itself.

I'd keep your parser outside File, and put it in lib/.

Answer (score 0):

I use to let classes that implement domain-related logic in the models folder. You should be aware that they won't be automaticly reloaded if let in the /lib folder.